# I deleted the log file in the docker container, now the new logs are now getting created. How to get the file with new logs?

Tags: docker, logging, dockerfile, containers

I used rm-rf  to delete the file, how can I get the file with new logs?

Comment: What file? Where? How were you previously getting the logs before you deleted the file? What image are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create new log file you must restart you app.
But how your restart your app in container?
Then just restart your container.